# Issues with Searching ListView (Android)

Tags: java, android, listview

I have been having trouble trying to get my Searchbox working to search the Listview for appropriate rows, and then displaying as required.

Basically, when I type in the searchbox, either the app crashed or gives me 'null object reference' errors from various files (ListView.java, TextView.java etc..)

I suspect it has a lot to do with inexperience on comparing strings between the EditText and the array created from JSON values. Displaying the listview is fine, searching it has been a frustrating hurdle. Would appreciate any help possible, thanks!

My code sections are as below,

**ListViewActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import com.example.myapplication.WaterWellRigsJsonUrl;
import com.example.myapplication.Rig;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listview;
private ArrayList<Rig> Rigs;
private ArrayList<Rig> RigsTemp;
private ArrayAdapter<Rig> adapter;
private ArrayAdapter<Rig> adapter2;
private EditText et;
String searchString = "";

private final static String TAG = ListViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private final static String url = "http://www.world-rigs.com/waterwellrigs/json.php";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    setListViewAdapter();
    getDataFromInternet();

    final EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            String searchString = s.toString();
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Rigs.size();i++) {
                    if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(Rigs.get(i).getName())) {
                        Rig rigtemp = new Rig();
                        rigtemp.setName(Rigs.get(i).getName());
                        rigtemp.setImageUrl(Rigs.get(i).getImageUrl());
                        rigtemp.setRigId(Rigs.get(i).getRigId());
                        RigsTemp.add(rigtemp);
                        Log.e("myTag2", "value:" + RigsTemp.size());
                    }
                }
            }
    adapter2 = new CustomListViewAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, R.layout.item_listview, RigsTemp);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }

    });
}

private void getDataFromInternet() {
    new WaterWellRigsJsonUrl(this, url).execute();
}

private void setListViewAdapter() {
    Rigs = new ArrayList<Rig>();
    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, Rigs);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

//parse response data after asynctask finished
public void parseJsonResponse(String result) {
    Log.i(TAG, result);
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json.getString("rig_array"));
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Rig rig = new Rig();
            rig.setName(jObject.getString("name"));
            rig.setImageUrl(jObject.getString("image"));
            rig.setRigId(jObject.getString("rigid"));
            Rigs.add(rig);
            Log.e("myTag", Rigs.get(i).getRigId());
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

**CustomListViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.myapplication.Rig;
import com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Rig> {

private Activity activity;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, List<Rig> rigs) {
    super(activity, resource, rigs);
    this.activity = activity;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate UI from XML file
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
        // get all UI view
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        // set tag for holder
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // if holder created, get tag from view
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Rig rig = getItem(position);

    holder.name.setText(rig.getName());
    holder.authorName.setText("WR" + rig.getRigId());
    Picasso.with(activity).load(rig.getImageUrl()).into(holder.image);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private TextView authorName;
    private ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        image = (SmartImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
       // SmartImageView image = (SmartImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        authorName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.author);
    }
 }

}
```

Also getting the following errors, which do get frustrating but I think it has something to do with null reference in my Adapter or RigsTemp array while searching...

```
01-30 13:17:45.300 16835-16835/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 16835 
             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
             at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:487)
             at com.example.myapplication.ListViewActivity$1.onTextChanged(ListViewActivity.java:84)
             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7663)
             at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7723)
             at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9440)
             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:964)
             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:515)
             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:454)
             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
             at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:685)
             at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:445)
             at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:340)
             at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize `RigsTemp` array

Comment: i would recommend implement Filterable interface in your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create two adapters and initialize them again and again. Create just one adapter and use `notifyDataSetChanged` to change data and update `ListView`

```
private ArrayList<Rig> RigsTemp;
private ArrayAdapter<Rig> adapter;
```

Change your function as follows:

```
private void setListViewAdapter() {
    Rigs = new ArrayList<Rig>();
    RigsTemp = new ArrayList<Rig>();
    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, R.layout.item_listview, RigsTemp);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

And Change the TextWatcher code with following code:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String searchString = myFilter.getText().toString();
    RigsTemp.clear();
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Rigs.size(); i++) {
            if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(Rigs.get(i).getName())) {
                    Rig rigtemp = new Rig();
                    rigtemp.setName(Rigs.get(i).getName());
                    rigtemp.setImageUrl(Rigs.get(i).getImageUrl());
                    rigtemp.setRigId(Rigs.get(i).getRigId());
                    RigsTemp.add(rigtemp);
                }
            }
    } else {
        // Only if you want to show all results when user has not entered anything in EditText
        // Else remove this line to show empty ListView at start
        RigsTemp.addAll(Rigs);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Hello Rehan, thanks for the response. I have tried your solution and it still doesn't work, so I've tried using Log printing and the Logct to check the textbox. The issue actually seems to be the equalsIgnoreCase, which just doesn't seem to work. Any help or experience in solving errors regarding this function?

Comment: Hello Rehan, sorry, the code does work. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: @AjitDenis I've updated the answer. You can change `String searchString = s.toString();` to `String searchString = myFilter.getText().toString();` so it will search using all text entered in the EditText.

Comment: @AjitDenis Please accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Hello Rehan, yeps, answer accepted. I also didn't know about .contains function, which is actually what I was looking for.

Comment: @AjitDenis Good that it worked for you. And use `toLowerCase` with `contains` for case insensitive searching!